# Adding a single file to Sublime Text project

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Is there a way to add only one file to Sublime Text project?

The file sits in a directory with other files and directories, that should not be included in the project.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although there's no exact feature, you can add the directory and exclude all the other files and folders:

```
"folders": [
  {
    "path": "path/to/the/folder",
    "folder_exclude_patterns": ["**/**"],
    "file_include_patterns": ["file_to_include"]
  }
]
```

Comment: What if the file is in the root folder?